# How to force content to jut out of a (vertically centered) table cell?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want to force the content of one of the cells in my table to overflow the cell width by a specified amount. With `c` columns, negative kerning does the trick. But I also want vertical alignment, and negative kerning no longer works with `m` columns.

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

%\begin{tabular}[h]{|M{1in}|M{1in}|M{1in}|}
\begin{tabular}[h]{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \rule{0.2in}{1in} &
  \rule{1in}{0.2in} &
  \rule{0.2in}{1in} \\
  \hline
  \rule{1in}{0.2in} &
  \rule{0.2in}{1in} &
  \rule{1in}{0.2in} \\
  \hline
  \rule{0.2in}{1in} &
  \kern-0.5in\rule{1.5in}{0.2in} &
  \rule{0.2in}{1in} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The bottom middle cell shows what I mean. Toggle the commenting on the `\begin{tabular}` lines to see it fail with `m` columns. How can I get it to work?

**Motivation:** I have a column containing a bunch of images with similar, aligned content. Most of them are the same width, but one is wider because the extra space contains some additional information like labels. I want the extra space to be ignored so that the images remain well aligned in my document. I don't want to simply use left- or right-alignment, because that wastes the extra space in the other cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\makebox` instead of the `\kern`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[h]{|M{1in}|M{1in}|M{1in}|}
%\begin{tabular}[h]{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \rule{0.2in}{1in} &
  \rule{1in}{0.2in} &
  \rule{0.2in}{1in} \\
  \hline
  \rule{1in}{0.2in} &
  \rule{0.2in}{1in} &
  \rule{1in}{0.2in} \\
  \hline
  \rule{0.2in}{1in} &
  \makebox[1in][r]{\rule{1.5in}{0.2in}} &
  \rule{0.2in}{1in} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Explanation: `\makebox[1in][r]{\rule{1.5in}{0.2in}}` puts the rule in a box of width `1in` and `r`ight-aligns it in the box.

[image]